# get the total values of a column in jtable

Tags: java, mysql

i use a jtable to display data retrieved from the database mysql, i need to get the total values of the third  column which is the balance column in the table 
  any help would be appreciated

```
     table_1 = new JTable();

    DefaultTableModel model =(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
        },
        new String[] {
            "YEAR", "TERM", "BALANCE",
        }
    ));
    table_1.setModel(model);
    table_1.getColumnModel().get-column(0).setPreferredWidth(100);
    table_1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(107);
    table_1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(130);
    scrollPane_3.setViewportView(table_1);

    btnSearch_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //database connection and retrieving data from database
    while(rs.next()){
     Vector<String> rowData = new Vector<>();
                         rowData.add(rs.getString(1));
                         rowData.add(rs.getString(2));
                         rowData.add(rs.getString(3));


                         // row++;
                         model.addRow(rowData);
          }
    }
   }
```

Comment: What are you getting when you run this code for a value?

Comment: when i run the code, it gives me everything i needed, but i wanted to get the sum of all the values in the third column and set it to textfield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use method `getValueAt(row index , column index)` to get value of a specific cell.and you can get sum as follow.

example

```
int total=0;
for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++){
    total +=Integer.parseInt( model.getValueAt(i, 2).toString() );// 3rd column . row column indexes are 0 based
}
```

Comment: You'd probably also want to convert the column index just in case the table gets rearranged, the way above only looks at the 3rd column.

Comment: total += model.getValueAt(i, 2);
i get the error
    
    the operator + = is undefined for the argument type (s)int,object

Comment: @abdulazizibrahim see my updated answer.you should either convert vale[object] to int or change data type of 3 rd column to integer like joop said.

Comment: it works but the problem is it displays the first row twice and  displays the sum but i need it to display the sum only

Comment: @abdulazizibrahim what where did you put this code?

Comment: after the code

   Vector<String> rowData = new Vector<>();
                         rowData.add(rs.getString(1));
                         rowData.add(rs.getString(2));
                         rowData.add(rs.getString(3));


                         // row++;
                         model.addRow(rowData);
                       int total=0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++){
                       total +=Integer.parseInt( model.getValueAt(i, 2).toString() );
}
          }

Comment: @abdulazizibrahim no no .you have to put outside of the while loop.not inside it

Comment: stil it displays the first row,displays the addition of the first + second row
and again displays the addition of the first second and third row

the table returns only three rows so i wanted it to display the last sum

Comment: @abdulazizibrahim i don't understand what you are saying.can you take a snapshot of your table and upload some where like http://imgur.com/ .so i can understand clearly .

Answer (score 1):

First use `Object[]` for a record, and `BigDecimal` for an amount.

```
 Object[] rowData = new Object[] {
     rs.getString(1),
     rs.getString(2),
     rs.getBigDecimal(3),
     rs.getString(4)};
 model.addRow(rowData);
```

Later adding can be done as:

```
  BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
  DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table_1.getModel();
  for (int row = 0; row < model.getRowCount(); ++row) {
      BigDecimal x = (BogDecimal) model.Value(row, 3 - 1);
      if (x != null) {
          sum = x.add(sum);
      }
  }
  return sum;
```

The reason for having correct types in the model is the possibility to have visual formatting per type/column.